# Symfony2 Assigning User Roles During Registration

Tags: php, symfony, roles, user-roles

I've followed the Symfony2 [Security documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) and have the entities, database and forms doing their thing. Trouble was I didn't have any users in my database so I completed the steps in the [Registration Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html), but in my opinion these should be better connected. The Registration docs say nothing about the roles. It seems to me the best time to assign a default role would be during the user registration. This is what I'm after but I'm a bit lost on how to do this considering the User Entity does not have any methods for adding roles. My question is how do I assign a default role ("ROLE_USER"), which is stored in the database, to users during registration?

Relevant Code:

User Entity: http://pastebin.com/zi8nWGb8

Role Entity: http://pastebin.com/Q8D5kB0A

UserRepository: http://pastebin.com/BLfAjgkt

Registration and Login Actions: http://pastebin.com/rdbAcBXu

The signupCreateAction is where I suspect the magic should happen or perhaps in the `__construct()` method of the user entity. I'm simply lost as to the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things first. You need to create accessor methods for both classes. This means creating:

```
/**
 * ...
 */
class TblUser
{
    // ...
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }

    public function setRoles(Collection $roles)
    {
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            $this->addRole($role);
        }
    }

    public function addRole(TblPrivilege $role)
    {
        if (!$this->roles->contains($role)) {
            $this->roles->add($role);
            $role->addUser($this);
        }
    }

    public function removeRole(TblPrivilege $role)
    {
        if ($this->roles->contains($role)) {
            $this->roles->removeElement($role);
            $role->removeUser($this);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * ...
 */
class TblPrivileges
{
    // ...
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function setUsers(Collection $users)
    {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $this->addUser($user);
        }
    }

    public function addUser(TblUser $user)
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users->add($user);
        }
    }

    public function removeUser(TblUser $user)
    {
        if ($this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users->removeElement($user);
        }
    }
}
```

For actually calling the $user->addRole() method, I would actually go for a Doctrine event subscriber, which would actually fetch the default role on persist (and thus, during registration). This is well documented on the [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events).

To register an event subscriber, you should look at the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-subscriber-class):

Comment: I have all your code applied (Thanks) and the event subscriber as well. My first question is how do I know that the prePersist even is called on a new entity rather than just an update? I don't have a second question yet, but I'm sure I will when I get further into this.

Comment: Next question: since I'm dealing with an empty database certain properties are not defined (TblPrivilege->users). When I try to add a user to the TblPrivilege I get an error. What's the best way to ensure these properties are instantiated. I was thinking of just checking in the addUser method if users is valid and if not instantiating it.

Comment: Got this working using your suggestions. I'm wondering if you could give me the answers to the 2 questions above though. Thanks

Comment: For your first question, the `prePersist` event is only called when a new object is being persisted. When the object is already managed by Doctrine (i.e. fetched from the database), you don't need to call the `persist()` method from the entity manager to save its values. Only the `flush()` method, as the entity manager tracks changes on all the entities that are managed.

Comment: For the second question, you need to make sure that for all collections, you actually instantiate these using `ArrayCollection`. That means that in the constructor of TblPrivileges, you need to have something like `$this->users = new ArrayCollection()`, and in TblUsers, you need `$this->privileges = new ArrayCollection()`. Otherwise Doctrine won't be able to handle the relation between the two.

Comment: Almost there. First question is good. Second question has a little problem. I do have the users collection instantiated in the constructor, however I'm not creating new entities on the roles side only fetching them from the database i.e. they already exist so the constructor initialization won't help. For now in each method I've checked to see if the users collection is set and initialize if not.

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you have defined a relation, Doctrine will automatically replace the content of your field with a `PersistentCollection` object, which proxies the collection's loading.
So you don't need to initialize the users collection if the object is already persisted.

Answer (score 0):

I use the FOSUserBundle to manage users and roles.  They have a facility called Groups that lets you manage the roles in the database.  That said this shouldn't be difficult to roll yourself.

The FOSUserBundle provides most of the things you need to manage users.

Comment: If he don't need all the biavior of FosUserBundle He can do the same thing that fos do for default role :

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php
see hasRole getRole and setRole

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this in your user entity

```
private $roles = array();

/**
 * Returns the roles or permissions granted to the user for security.
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;

    // guarantees that a user always has at least one role for security
    if (empty($roles)) {
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';
    }

    return array_unique($roles);
}

public function setRoles($roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;
}
```